# Add window to the right of two horizontally split windows

Tags: window, frames, emacs24.4

Following scenario:
1) I start emacs and the initial frame is as follow:

```
+---------------+
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
+---------------+
```

1) I split the window horizontally (C-x 2).

```
+---------------+
|               |
|               |
+---------------+
|               |
|               |
+---------------+
```

2) now I would like to have one third window, which stretches over the two horizontal ones, resulting in a layout as follow:

```
+----------+----+
|          |    |
|          |    |
+----------+    +
|          |    |
|          |    |
+----------+----+
```

How can I achieve this easily without deleting one window (C-x 0), splitting vertically (C-x 3) and then splitting each window horizontally again (C-x 2) ?

My real setup is obviously much more complex, and I resort at the moment to creating a second frame which I would like to avoid.

The same question can be asked for horizontal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to split the frame's root window which encompasses both of your windows, thereby allowing you to add a third window at any side.  There is no built-in command to do that though, so here's some example code to define commands for this particular task:

```
(defun my-split-root-window (size direction)
  (split-window (frame-root-window)
                (and size (prefix-numeric-value size))
                direction))

(defun my-split-root-window-below (&optional size)
  (interactive "P")
  (my-split-root-window size 'below))

(defun my-split-root-window-right (&optional size)
  (interactive "P")
  (my-split-root-window size 'right))
```

Comment: Thanks - works perfectly. I'll add it to my emacs.el file.

Comment: Just one question - what does the ```"P"``` in ```(interactive "P")``` mean?

Comment: It tells Emacs to read in the prefix value in raw form in case the command is executed interactively.  So, if you're invoking the command with a `M-9`, it would pass a value of `(9)` which is turned into `9` and tells the command to use such a size when splitting.  Passing nothing would give it `nil` which would be ignored.  The usual `"p"` form would interpret no prefix argument as `1`, that's why I'm going the extra mile here.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. To bind it to a global key, ```(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 6") 'my-split-root-window-below)``` does not work as I have to specify a value - how can I do this apart from f=defining a helper function?

Comment: Works just fine here, thanks to the `interactive` form which reads in the argument when using the command *interactively*.  The argument shouldn't even need to be specified when using the command programmatically because it's marked as optional.

Comment: Don't know what I did - it's working now. Thanks a lot.